# ATI Radeon 2900 causes Radeon driver to crash on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, radeon, crash, amd-graphics, nomodeset

FULL DISCLOSURE: First time Ubuntu user here.

I currently have an ATI Radeon HD 2900 in my PC (I believe R600); I can boot into Ubuntu 16.04, however it crashes almost as soon as Unity loads, and I get the following error message repeated rapidly at a full screen command prompt:

"Radeon Ring 0 stalled for more than _______"

I can boot into Ubuntu with "nomodeset" as an argument at grub, however the display get's set to something insane like LESS than 640x480, and I can barely do anything.

The Radeon driver specifically states it supports my card... are there tweaks that can be done to try and mitigate this issue with the Radeon driver? Is there any hope?

Comment: Did you find a solution to the issue?